# Non-finitely generated modules over PID

Tags: linear-algebra, modules

It is well known fact that if $ M $ is a non-zero *finitely generated* module over $ R $, where $ R $ is PID, then it can be represented as
$$ M=\oplus_{i=1}^n{M_{p_i}}, $$
where $ p_i\in R $ are primes.

But what happens if $ M $ is *not* finitely generated? As far as I know, this assumption is needed to show that $ \mathrm{Ann}_R(M)\ne 0. $ So, is it possible that annihilator is trivial in this case? And are there any analogues to the statement above? (for example, that $ M $ is *infinite* direct sum of $ p_i $-modules)

Comment: I mean, all modules in commutative algebra are (possibly not finitely generated) $\Bbb Z$-modules...

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbf Q/\mathbf Z$ is an example of a torsion $\mathbf Z$-module with zero annihilator.